# unittest.mock doesn't work when tests are run with pytest

Tags: python, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I have the following project structure:

```
tests/
└── messenger/
    └── messaging_test.py
app/
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
└── messenger/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── messaging.py
```

Inside `messaging.py` module there's a function `send_schedule` with the following lines:

```
talks = models.Talk.query.all()
raise ValueError(str(talks))  # the debug output
```

I'm trying to patch the `models.Talk.query.all()` call. Inside `messaging_test.py` there's the following test:

```
@patch('app.models.Talk.query.all')
def test_send_schedule(self, all_query_mock):
    all_query_mock.return_value = []
    for talk_id in range(1, 6):
        talk_mock = MagicMock(id=talk_id, title=str(talk_id), speaker_facebook_id=1)
        all_query_mock.return_value.append(talk_mock)
    with vcr.use_cassette('vcr_cassettes/send_schedule.yaml'):
        response = messaging.send_schedule(self.access_token, self.user_id)

    self.assertTrue('recipient_id' in response)
    self.assertTrue('message_id' in response)
    self.assertEqual(response['recipient_id'], self.user_id)
```

When I run the test with `python3 -m pytest tests/messenger/messaging_test.py` command, `ValueError` outputs an empty list, which signifies that the call wasn't patched. Can you suggest a fix to that?

What did I do to solve the issue:

- Read ["Where to patch"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) paragraph of documentation. This led me to suspicion that `pytest` runs my tests in a weird way.
- Tried to use `pytest-mock` but failed to figure out how to use it with `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I clearly have done a bad research on this. There was no problem with `pytest` module. In order to fix the issue, I needed to patch `app.models.Talk`, not the strange `app.models.Talk.query.all`. After I patched the class, I simply added the properties I needed:

```
    @patch('app.models.Talk')
def test_send_schedule(self, talk_class_mock):
    talk_mocks = []
    for talk_id in range(1, 6):
        talk_mock = MagicMock(id=talk_id, title=str(talk_id), speaker_facebook_id=1)
        talk_mocks.append(talk_mock)
    query_mock = MagicMock(all=MagicMock(return_value=talk_mocks))
    talk_class_mock.query = query_mock
    with vcr.use_cassette('vcr_cassettes/send_schedule.yaml'):
        response = messaging.send_schedule(self.access_token, self.user_id)

    self.assertTrue('recipient_id' in response)
    self.assertTrue('message_id' in response)
    self.assertEqual(response['recipient_id'], self.user_id)
```